# Как сделать эффект оттяжки у RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Как сделать такой эффект как у iOS когда в `RecyclerView` доходишь до последнего элемента(или до первого), то когда тянешь дальше то вью отьезжает вниз с оттяжкой как бы давая понять, что это крайний элемент в списке.

В андроиде это реализовано по другому, появляется такой полукруг но мне нужна реализация как в иос.

Как это сделать? Куда смотреть?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно сделать на основе `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот нужное Вам решение, на англоязычной версии SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758635/ios-like-over-scroll-effect-on-android